# Using BACK button to restart the previous activity

Tags: android, android-activity, back-button

There are two activities. Following is the first activity.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final CharSequence[] items = {"Pick from gallery", "Shoot now"};

        //Prepare the list dialog box
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        //Set its title
        builder.setTitle("Choose a video");

        //Set the list items along with checkbox and assign with the click listener
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            // Click listener
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                if(items[item]=="Pick from gallery"){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Choose a video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Intent r1= new Intent("com.asin.amit.PIC");
                    r1.putExtra("choice", 1);
                    startActivity(r1);
                }

                if(items[item]=="Shoot now"){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record a video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Intent r1= new Intent("com.asin.amit.PIC");
                    r1.putExtra("choice", 2);
                    startActivity(r1);
                }    
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

        //display dialog box
        alert.show();
    } 
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unknown issue, Kindly restart the application", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When the user is in second activity and presses BACK button, I want this first activity to start but right now only a black screen appears, the pop up menu is not visible. I have to rotate the mobile to get the menu. How to make it by default ? Also, is using `try` for `super.onCreate` required ?

**EDIT**
one more issue is that in second activity i am doing a  no of tasks, first task is picking a video from gallery. If `BACK` is pressed at this stage then a blank screen appears, I have to press `BACK` again. How to avoid this ?

Comment: are you calling `finish()` anywhere in your first activity?

Comment: just add onResume method in your Activity and put code for pop up menu in onResume method

Comment: @GAMA I am not using `finish`

Answer (score 2):

Try writing `alert.show();` in the **onResume()** method rather then in **onCreate()**.

onResume() of first activity will be called when user pres back button from second activity.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 2):

U can used this method to call the back Activity

This is a example i have used in my app

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            // _progressDialog.dismiss();
            if (getIntent().getExtras().getString("From").equals("Menu")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        VideoTypes.class);
                intent.putExtra("From",
                        getIntent().getExtras().getString("From"));
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

i hope this will help u

Answer (score 0):

`super.onCreate()` is required. If you don't call it, the app will crash.

You can use [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29), instead of `startActivity()`. So you can catch the event when the second activity is finished, then show up your menu again.